# Post multible data from CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, checkboxlist

Im trying to display multible data from a checkbox list what is populated from my database. So far i have written some lines of code. But i dont know why it is not displaying data as it should.

> public void PopulateCheckBoxList()
>       {
>           var db = new DataClassesDataContext();
>
> ```
>     var data = (from x in db.tblCategories
>                 orderby x.CategoryName
>                 select x);
>     CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
>     CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
>     CheckBoxList1.DataSource = data;
>     CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
> }
> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
>     {
>         if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
>         {
>             Label1.Text += CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: In what way is it not working?  What output do you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: I may be wrong, but should the LINQ part be closed with .ToList() ?

Comment: @RafałCzabaj It should not be needed, calling `DataBind()` on the checkboxlist will enumerate `data`.

Comment: Have tried ToList() but with no succes. What happends when i run the button event is what the checkbox clears of all selected values and the label does not display any data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted the code that calls `PopulateCheckBoxList()` so theres some educated guesswork here but assuming it is in `Page_Load` then make sure that you are only calling it when there isn't a postback otherwise it will be repopulated and the selected values wiped out before the button_click event hand;ler runs.:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateCheckBoxList();
    }
}
```